Showing icon of the application associated with the filetype (Gnome Files)
There is a lot of questions and answers on associating specific icons with specific filetypes. I'd however like to avoid that and instead show the icon of the application that will open the file, as this would resolve my icon problems for a bunch of cases at once.
I can see that the Files app knows  that I want to open .Rproj files with RStudio:

it also knows this is an "R Project file" (probably mostly unrelated, unless I go through the "icon for filetype" way)

Is it possible to make the Files app (or any other standard file browsing app) to show the icon of the associated application?

This https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238924/assign-an-icon-to-a-custom-mimetype and the Related questions may help.
